# Is it possible to monitor changes in an internal class?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting

I'm using CSScript to load C# files as scripts at run-time. These scripts inherit from classes inside the host application. For faster loading I'm caching the scripts, or rather the compiled assemblies, and load those instead if they're newer than the script file.

Now, if a method inside the host application changes, the script naturally has to be recompiled, otherwise you get an exception, because the calls in the child don't match the parent anymore. But I don't want to recompile every script every time I recompile the application, because most of the time the changes aren't related to the script base classes.

Is it possible to create a kind of "snapshot" of the methods in the base classes, their methods and arguments, during run-time (reflection?), to be able to tell when something changed, so I know I have to recompile the scripts?

Comment: You could recompile on the first occurrence of an exception that is not created by user code but rather from incompatible assemblies. (I do not know whether they are clearly distinguishable, e.g. `TargetInvocationException`)

Comment: @Samuel Hm, that could work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate hash values for your script files and compare them when loading. If the hash value has changed, then the script file has been modified.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/307020

Comment: The problem is not the script being modified, but the base classes in the host application.

Comment: Not sure how CSScript works, but do you have to recompile your scripts if they reference interfaces in the host application? Of course only when the interface it self has not been modified. You could also create hash values for the host assemblies or rely on the version numbers.